# Use a dict as the composite key of another python dict (key-value pair)

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am trying to frame a data structure to do the following operation.

I want a key-value pair that looks something like this.

```
{
  {"color": "red", "shape": "circle"}: {data: [{}, {}, {}, {}]}
, {"color": "blue", "shape": "square"}: {data: [{}, {}, {}, {}]}
, {"color": "blue", "shape": "circle"}: {data: [{}, {}, {}, {}]}
, {"color": "red", "shape": "square"}: {data: [{}, {}, {}, {}]}
}
```

What I want is to return a json style dict object when color is red, shape is circle. Return a different json style dict object when color is blue, shape is square etc.

So, my key is not really a regular key. It is kind of a composite key. Please suggest

Comment: JSON allows only string keys in the dicts.

Comment: And the only way this would work is if you created your own class that inherits the build-in dict type and implement your own `__hash__` function, but that in turn would result in what i presume a string anyway, so just iterate over the dict and if the key object is a dict convert it to a string object. You could then potentially loop over it in say JavaScript and convert the key (string) to a dict by loading it into the decoder over yet another loop. Two-step-conversion or just implement `__hash__` in a user defined class-dict.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done in Python.  You'll receive a `TypeError`.  The reason for this is that a dictionary key **must** be a hashable object, which a `dict` is not.  As an example, try this:

```
>>> d0 = {'foo': 'bar',}
>>> assert d0 == {'foo': 'bar'}
>>> d1 = {d0: 'baz',}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
>>> hash(d0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
>>>
```

The reason that `dict`s are not hashable is that they are *mutable* objects.  This means (roughly) that they can change (although it's a little more subtle than that, to quote the Python docs).  IIRC, under the hood, Python uses hash tables to implement dictionary keys, so if an object isn't hashable, it can't be used as a key.  See the [Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html) section of the Python docs for more information on mutable and immutable objects.

As others have said, you should use an immutable object, such as a tuple or a [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html), for your key:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> colors = 'red blue'.split(' ')
>>> shapes = 'circle square'.split(' ')
>>> Figure = namedtuple('Figure', ('color', 'shape'))
>>> my_dict = {Figure(color, shape): {'data': [{}, {}, {}, {},]}
...            for color in colors for shape in shapes}
>>> assert my_dict == {Figure(color='blue', shape='circle'): {'data': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}, Figure(color='blue', shape='square'): {'data': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}, Figure(color='red', shape='circle'): {'data': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}, Figure(color='red',shape='square'): {'data': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}}
>>> assert my_dict[('blue', 'circle')] == {'data': [{}, {}, {}, {}]}
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON does not support what you are looking for, neither does Python since `dict` objects are not hashable. I'd go for a `namedtuple` in this case, since you will (hopefully) know up-front what constituents your key will have:

```
from collections import namedtuple
MyKey = namedtuple("MyKey", "color shape".split())

my_dict = {
   MyKey(color="red", shape="circle"): {...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a dict object as key in python. What I would do is to use something *immutable* as key: instead of the dict object itself I use its string representation.